# While calling SleepConditionVariableSRW() what should be the flag value to indicate that the SRW lock is in exclusive mode?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

The MSDN documentation for [SleepConditionVariableSRW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686304.aspx) states that -

> Flags [in] -
>   If this parameter is CONDITION_VARIABLE_LOCKMODE_SHARED,
>   the SRW lock is in shared mode. Otherwise, the lock is in exclusive
>   mode.

From this I inferred that any value other than **CONDITION_VARIABLE_LOCKMODE_SHARED** will imply exclusive mode SRW lock. However, when I tried providing a flag value of `CONDITION_VARIABLE_LOCKMODE_SHARED + 1` the function `SleepConditionVariableSRW()` failed after a few tries.*

I set the flags value as 0 and all the testcases involving `SleepConditionVariableSRW()` passed (over and over again).

Can anybody confirm if the value of this flag is supposed to be '0' only to imply exclusive mode SRW lock? I couldn't find any mention of it in the MSDN documentation.

* *I tried other non-zero values too.*

Answer (score 1):

Formal parameters called *Flags* are generally implemented as bitflags. In case of [SleepConditionVariableSRW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686304.aspx), there's only a single value currently in use. The value of `CONDITION_VARIABLE_LOCKMODE_SHARED` is `0x1` (i.e. "Bit 0"). All other bits are currently unused.

To use exclusive lock mode, bit 0 has to be unset. Since there aren't any other flags currently defined, the only legal input for exclusive lock mode is 0.

Comment: Could you provide a link (MSDN preferably) which states so explicitly?

Comment: @work.bin: No. Those are *"ground rules"* that you are supposed to know. They aren't explicitly documented.

Comment: If what you say (about the implementation of `Flags`) is true then shouldn't any even number be fine (to imply exclusive SRW lock)? My tests with even numbers greater than 1 failed too.

Comment: @work.bin: Currently, only the LSB (bit 0) is used. Setting any other bits can easily be verified as invalid input, and rejected by the API call. APIs are not required to validate input, but most will. I would assume that calling `GetLastError` on failure will return 87 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`). If a future update to the API adds new flags, other bit patterns will be supported, and some even numbers will imply exclusive lock mode. Until then, you cannot set any bits other than bit 0.